# Bootstrap navbar-expand-xl collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im using `navbar navbar-expand-xl`which should hide my nav menu, and it's working with resolution lower than 1200px but then my `collapse` button hides til 1000px and then shows of. What I need to change to let my collapse button shows at less than 1200px not 1000px.

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark fixed-top menu-nawigacyjne">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Insurance Group</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          Menu<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav  mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="p-2 text-white"  href="/stronaGlowna">Strona Główna </a>
            </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="p-2 text-white" href="/przegladajUbezpieczenia">Ubezpieczenia </a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="p-2 text-white" href="/informacje">Informacje </a>

        </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="login-form">

            <form action ="/stronaGlowna" method = "post" class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">


                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" id ="login" name = "login" placeholder="Adres e-mail" required >
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" id = "haslo" name = "haslo" placeholder="Hasło" required >
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf"  value="f20d6efe-5ecb-4368-bada-a55dfdd67fb5" /> 
                    <button class="btn btn-success custom-width" type="submit">Zaloguj się</button>
                    <a class="p-2 text-white" href="/przypomnijHaslo">Nie pamiętam hasła </a>
                </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

You can also check it on live: http://www.aplikacja-ubezpieczenia.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove `d-lg-none` from the toggler. This is preventing the toggler from displaying on `lg` and up. When the navbar collapses after `xl`, the toggler is still hidden because the `lg` breakpoint which is above 992 px.

You don't need to use anu `d-*` class on the toggler since having `navbar-expand-xl` will automaticlly handle the toggler display.

Comment: Thank you for answer and also for explanation :)